# Boot CD - mouse enabled

Tags: boot, usb, mouse, bootloader

Is there a boot manager (like Ultimate Boot CD) which enables the use of a USB mouse?

The reason I need one is because I'm trying to reinstall Windows 7 on a computer that doesn't have a PS/2 port. Unfortunately I don't have any USB keyboards. I've ordered a PS/2 to USB adapter but it won't get it for another couple of weeks.

The only way I see to reinstall Windows 7 without a keyboard is by the use of WDS, however to use that I need to boot from the network on the PC - the only thing that springs to mind for this problem is a boot CD with USB mouse enabled.

Comment: You mention UBCD... have you looked into using UBCD4Win? http://www.ubcd4win.com/ in any case, UBCD isn't a boot manager, but has several on the disc you can use.  Of course, there is always making yourself a BartPE disc http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/

Comment: I've routinely installed windows 7 with a USB keyboard - there shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: "Unfortunately I don't have any USB keyboards"

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling "Legacy USB Mouse" support in the BIOS.

Related SU question: [What does "Legacy USB Mouse" support in a BIOS mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/303365/what-does-legacy-usb-mouse-support-in-a-bios-mean)