# Will PS/2 keyboard work if use purple adapter but BIOS has no USB Legacy mode?

Tags: usb, keyboard, adapter, ps2, ps2-keyboard

As I get it a purple adapter is for a keyboard (PS/2 to USB). Does it make sense to buy one if I have no USB Legacy mode in UEFI settings?

Comment: What model of MB do you have?

Comment: @HackSlash Dell Inc. 0XT9M4

Answer (score 0):

[USB Legacy Mode](https://superuser.com/questions/303365/what-does-legacy-usb-mouse-support-in-a-bios-mean) has nothing to do with using adapters. The function is to emulate a PS/2 device for USB devices during boot. If you can boot your OS now without it then changing to a PS/2 keyboard with adapter won't make a difference. The adapter effectively makes it a USB device.

With DELL BIOS they often have different naming for features and different features all together. The only way to know for sure if it's going to work is to test it. I think it will work.

If it doesn't work with a cheap passive adapter there are [active USB to PS\2 port devices that will host the PS\2 keyboard for sure](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=10934).